# Remove selected node from Tree

Tags: javascript, json, angular, tree

I am displaying a tree in Angular2 application using angular-tree-component (https://angular2-tree.readme.io).

I need to give user the capability to select any node in the tree and delete it. This should remove the selected node and all it's children (if it's a leaf node, then just the node). When user is done, the pruned tree will be send to the server and saved there.

In the below example, user selects 'Node 1-2' and clicks on Delete. This removes 'Node 1-2, 'Node 1' and 'Node 2' from the view and underlying Javascript object updated. User can then click another button (say, Save) to save the updated object on the Server.

[image: Node selected in Tree]

In order to accomplish this, I wrote the following code which is called on click of Delete button. I store the id of the selected node, and then iterate over the complete tree to find that id. When the id matches, I use the 'delete' keyword to delete 'id' and 'text'. However, 'delete children' does not work.

```
deleteSelectedNode() { 
    //Get the node which was selected by the user  
    let nodeToDelete: TreeNode = this.myService.getActiveNode();
    //id will be unique, can be used to identify the node
    let idToDelete = nodeToDelete.data.id; 
    this.traverseTree(this.nodes[0], idToDelete);
  }

  traverseTree(obj, idToDelete: string) {

    for (var k in obj) {
      if (typeof obj[k] == "object" && obj[k] !== null) {
        this.traverseTree(obj[k], idToDelete);
      }

      else {
        if (k === 'id') {
          let id = obj[k];
          if (id === idToDelete) {
            console.log('ID Matched ' + id);
            delete obj['id'];
            delete obj['text'];
            delete obj['children']; 
            break;
          }
        } 
      }
    }
  }
```

Below is the JSON which is rendering the tree.

```
{
        "children": [
            {
                "children": [
                    {
                        "text": "Node 1",
                        "id": "A493"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Node 2",
                        "id": "A494"
                    }
                ],
                "text": "Node 1-2",
                "id": "A491"
            },
            {
                "children": [
                    {
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "text": "Node 3",
                                "id": "A5ab"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Node 4",
                                "id": "A5ac"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Node 5",
                                "id": "A5ad"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Node 6",
                                "id": "A5ae"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Node 7",
                                "id": "A5af"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Node 8",
                                "id": "A5b0"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Node 9",
                                "id": "A5b1"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Node 10",
                                "id": "A5b2"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Node 11",
                                "id": "A5b3"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Node 12",
                                "id": "A5b4"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Node 13",
                                "id": "A6da"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Node 14",
                                "id": "A6db"
                            }
                        ],
                        "text": "Node 1-14",
                        "id": "A495"
                    },
                    {
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "text": "Node 15",
                                "id": "A6dc"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Node 16",
                                "id": "A6dd"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Node 17",
                                "id": "A6de"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Node 18",
                                "id": "A6df"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Node 19",
                                "id": "A6e0"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Node 20",
                                "id": "A6e1"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Node 21",
                                "id": "A6e2"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Node 22",
                                "id": "A6e3"
                            }
                        ],
                        "text": "Node 15-22",
                        "id": "A496"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Node 23",
                        "id": "A497"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Node 24",
                        "id": "A498"
                    }
                ],
                "text": "Node 23-24",
                "id": "A492"
            }
        ],
        "text": "Node 1-24",
        "id": "A490"
    }
```

How can I delete the complete node, including children? Also, is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily trough parent reference

```
deleteNode() {
    let nodeToDelete: TreeNode = this.tree.treeModel.getActiveNode();
    if (nodeToDelete.level === 1) {
      this.nodes = this.nodes.filter((n) => n.id !== nodeToDelete.id);
    } else {
      nodeToDelete.parent.children = nodeToDelete.parent.children.filter((n) => n.id !== nodeToDelete.id);
    }    
  }
```